# Grouping windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, gnome-shell

I have a tkinter application that has a main window (a Tk) and an additional window (a Toplevel).

I want these windows to group together in the window manager (GNOME Shell). I believe it is necessary to have both the WM_CLASS resource and the WM_CLASS name to be set the same for both windows in order for this to happen.

Setting `className` on Tk and setting `class` on Toplevel to my application name seems to change the WM_CLASS name but not the resource, which is why I think they're not grouping. `xprop WM_CLASS` on the windows shows my chosen name for both entries on the Tk: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "myapp", "Myapp"`. For the Toplevel, it shows a tk_uid for the first element: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "140626444609872", "Myapp"`.

I also tried setting the titles of the windows, but it seemed to make no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wm group` command to group windows together.  Some operating systems / window managers may not respect this setting.

In tkinter, you can do this by calling `group` on the Toplevel instance with the root Tk instance as an argument.

References: [wm (tk)](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm), [wm (tkinter)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm)

Comment: This worked! It turns out the WM_CLASS wasn't what I needed. Please add to your answer that in tkinter, you need to do top_level.group(root), where top_level is the Toplevel, and root is your Tk instance. Thanks!

Comment: Edited it myself, actually.